# Trying to get data back as an array of object but getting array of array object in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Controller

```
    $activity_session = array();

    foreach($activities_by_category as $activity)  
    {
        $activity_session[] =  $this->users_model->search_sessions_by_activity($activity->activity_id);
    }
```

Model

```
    function search_sessions_by_activity($activity_id){

      $this->db->where('activity_by_id',$activity_id);
      $query = $this->db->get('activity_session');  
      return $query->result(); 
    }
```

Getting json objects as array

[image]

Comment: Ok? So just decode it? What is the problem?

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Comment: This is also totally unclear, and again picture instead of the actual adta

Answer (score 0):

Change your model with

```
    function search_sessions_by_activity($activity_id){
    $this->db->where('activity_by_id',$activity_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('activity_session');  
    return $query->result_array(); 
    }
```

hope it's working.